# How to access Device ID in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, portability

I am making a Portable class library (portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80) and I need some kind of ID that is Unique to device. I can't use `EasClientDeviceInformation` class, because I don't have access to `Windows.Security` namespace; I also don't have access to `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")`. Is there any PCL library that offers this functionality, or any other workaround to get any kind of Unique Device ID?